# Windows Phone - Cordova - Select crash

Tags: angularjs, cordova, crash, windows-phone

I've got a strange problem on my Windows Phone 10 App.

Setup:

- Cordova 6.2
- Windows Platform 4.4.2
- Angular 1.5.5
- Angular Material v1.1.0-rc.5
- Angular-Translate v.2.7.2

Inside my app I got a select-control:

```
<select style="width:100%;height:40px;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;" ng-model="isoCodeList.region">
     <option ng-repeat="entry in ::isoCodeList.list track by $index" value="{{::entry}}">
        {{::"ISO_" + entry | translate}}
    </option>
</select>
```

The isoCodeList looks like:

```
$scope.isoCodeList.list = ['AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG',...]
```

The translation labels looks like:

```
"ISO_AE": "United Arab. Emirates"
```

When I open the select-control **1 second later the app crashes**.

The problem doesn't exists while I debug the app via Visual-Studio, it just occures when the App is deployed and downloaded from the Windows-Store.

Also this issues doesn't occure on a Windows-Phone 8.1 device, just on Windows-Phone 10, but both get the same .appx-file.

Anyone experienced the same problem?

PS: I can't use the standard angular-material md-select because it needs more then 20 to 30 seconds to open the whole control.

Thanks in advance

Graphefruit

Comment: What does `crash`mean? Have you tried deploying your app through `usb debugging` to see any potential `console.logs`? Maybe include a `https://jsconsole.com/` logger so you can trace the log online to see what's going on, when the problem occures on the device. I think only then you'll have some insights about the actual problem.

Comment: With crash I mean the app is closing. I'm debugging via usb (with Visual-Studio) but here the problem doesn't even occure.
The problem is that console.logs won't be helping in this case because its an issue inside the app, an javascript error wouldn't crash the whole app even if its not inside a `try catch`

Comment: `a javascript error wouldn't crash the whole app even if its not inside a try catch` - not always true - infinite loops can give that result to the app. On the other hand, make sure you have added the correct permission in the `AndroindManifest.xml` file. Using permissions in the app which aren't in the manifest, can cause your application to behave as described above.

Comment: @daan.desmedt thanks for your feedback, but it isn't `Android` its `Windows` second I don't know which permissions a `select` should get, because no filesystem, internet or something like this is accessed. 
Maybe the infinite loop could get a problem buts a simple `ng-repeat` with a simple array, so I don't know where there should get an inifite loop?

Comment: I reported this issue to Microsoft and it was marked as fixed a few hours ago. It seems to affect Windows Phone 8.1 apps rolled out on Windows 10 Mobile 10.0.14393 only. So I guess, as soon as this fix is rolled out, everything should work as expected again. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9529349/